# Calculate Exponentially-Weighted Covariance Matrix over Finite Window

Tags: programming, covariance-matrix

I have an `(n,m)` array (specifically containing asset returns over `n` days for `m` assets). I'm trying to calculate the rolling exponentially-weighted covariance matrix for these assets over this time frame, but I want to limit how much data with which each covariance matrix is calculated.

To be more specific, I'm wanting to calculate these covariance matrices using 20-observation half-lives, but I don't want to include more than 40 observations in each of these calculations.

I've come as far as constructing a pandas DataFrame which has a shape of `(n, m, 40)`, so each value of `n` contains the last 40 observations of the `m` assets. I was thinking I'd be able to calculate a single exponentially-weighted covariance matrix with 20-observation half-life at each `n` using the data in that row , but I'm coming up short. Am I able to calculate it this way or is there a different approach I should take?

**Edit**:
I'm looking to avoid `for` loops in this solution.

Comment: It's not clear ( atleast to me ) what 20 observation half lives means ? There is a parameter in exponential smoothing usually denoted as $\lambda$ and this parameter maps to some half-life by solving $\lambda^{HL} = \frac{1}{2}$ where $HL$ is the half life you want.

Comment: Th above assumes that the ES model is: $ \hat{Cov}_{t} = \lambda \times \hat{Cov}_{t-1} + (1-\lambda) \times Cov_{t}$.

Comment: I assume the OP means lambda^20 = 0.5 for the comment re half life.

Comment: What is the perceived benefit of truncating the EWMA? It can be shown that the effective window length of an EWMA is 1/(-AF * ln(Lambda)) where AF is your annualisation factor (252?) and lambda is your discrete decay parameter. It is effective already truncated and as it is Markovian, it is rather kind computationally (unlike true finite window measures)

Comment: @markleeds by "half lives" I'm referring to the particular mapping to $\lambda$, as you mentioned.

Comment: @JamesSpencer-Lavan My goal with this measurement is to have an estimate of the covariance matrix that is sufficiently sensitive to recent data but also doesn't include stale outlier data. For example, suppose the ideal "sensitivity" is equivalent to a 20-day half life. If there are some observations in the past that are outliers (say >40 days in the past), they will still notably influence my estimate of the covariance matrix, which I don't want since I don't think that observations >40 days ago should have much of an influence. Therefore, I'm wanting to truncate the data.

Comment: Hi: I think you are saying that you when you calculate the second term $Cov_t$, you would like  a recursive way of calculating it so that you don't have to calculate the whole thing over again as KermittFrog described.  I'm not 100 percent sure but I would doubt that such an algorithm exists.  Eric Zivot has written  about EWMA of covariance matrices so maybe check that out.

Comment: HI: I don't know if its extremely fast but maybe find the function, CovEWMA, that he refers to on page 3 of this. https://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ589/amath546econ589hw4spring2013.pdf

Comment: Note that in the above, Eric's $(1-\lambda)$ is my $\lambda$. Things can get messy ( and wrong ) quickly  if one is not careful about how $\lambda$ is defined so be careful with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are aiming to compute a series of covariance matrices based on windows of your return data. To this end, let $X$ denote the $n\times k$ matrix of observed returns for $n$ dates and $k$ instruments. Further, you have a window of length $h<n$.

Then, the typical entry $(k,l)$of each component covariance matrix is calculated as (assuming zero mean)

$$
C_i(k,l)=\sum_{t=i}^{h+i-1}w_tx_{k,t}x_{l,t}=X_i^TWX_i
$$

where $X_i$ is the $i$th window of the data matrix, i.e.

$$
X_i\equiv \begin{pmatrix}
x_{1,i}&x_{2,i}&\ldots&x_{k,i}\\
x_{1,i+1}&x_{2,i+1}&\ldots&x_{k,i+1}\\
\ldots&\ldots&\ldots&\ldots\\
x_{1,i+h-1}&x_{2,i+h-1}&\ldots&x_{k,i+h-1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and $W$ is a diagonal matrix of the weights. The corresponding computation is a simple `for`-loop.
HTH?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kermittfrog. You are understanding me correctly, and your answer makes sense to me. However, and I neglected to state this in the initial question, I'm hoping to find a vectorized way of calculating this (I've updated my question to include this now). Being that I have an `(n,k,h)` DF, I was hoping I could calculate the matrices using pd.DataFrame.ewm().cov() along a specific axis, but I haven't been able to make that work.

Comment: Vectorisation only makes sense if 1) your data is arranged neatly in memory (the prog. language should help), 2) the operator is optimised accordingly (again, your prog. language will do that).  What you are looking for is an operation that maps an $n\times k$ matrix into a $n\times k \times h$ tensor. You can do that, of course, using tensor algebra. There should be packages available ('tensor' in both R and Python). But note that this would require both $X$ and $W$ to be inflated in such a way that their tensor products will yield the $n\times k\times h$ object...

Comment: Long story short: If there's no yet-predefined-function available, simply use a loop. Unless you require low latencies, but then you'd not be using Python to begin with, no?

Comment: Fair enough! Python is the sole language I'm working with right now, and I'm trying to be as efficient with it as I can. I might look into creating a Cython file if the `for` loop is the only way I can make this happen. Thanks for the feedback.